# generating pairs of random numbers in java such that p !=q

Tags: java, random

I am trying to create pairs of random integers in the range `[0,n)` .
I need to make sure that for any input `n`, the numbers created ,say p,q are such that `p != q`

I tried to use `java.util.Random` with `seed` sothat I can reproduce the  result ..I tried inputs `100,200,400,800` and they all created p,q such that `p !=q` .But at 1600 two pairs were with `p == q`

```
public static void generate(int size){      
    Random ran = new Random();
    ran.setSeed(123456L);       
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        int p = ran.nextInt(size);
        int q = ran.nextInt(size);
        if(p==q)
            System.out.println(p+" equals "+q);
        //else
            //System.out.println(p+" "+q);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    generate(1600);

}
```

this gave

```
692 equals 692
843 equals 843
```

I am sure there is some way to make sure that p != q for any input n.. but I cannot recall the math needed

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want a seed that does not generate consecutive equals? Because you could just check `p` and  `q` and regenerate a random value if they were equal.

Comment: There is a possibility _if your random numer is odd_: always take `max - generatedNumber`, it will _always_ give a different result. That is, if numbers start at 1, not 0

Comment: Well... not for *any* `n`.  If `n` is 0, they will always match. :)  Also, be wary of declaring a seed like that.  Your program will now give the same results every time.

Comment: Do you want to generate such pairs uniformly at random? I'm not totally sure the proposed approaches do this. Intuitively it seems to be safer to create 2 numbers and reject the pair if they are equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep picking until they don't match.

```
int p = ran.nextInt(size);
int q;

do {
    q = ran.nextInt(size);
} while(p==q);
```

Comment: and you could do {...} while (p==q) too

Answer (score 4):

Generate one number in [0,n) and the other one in [0,n-1)
If the second one is superior (inclusive) to the first one, add one.

```
int p = ran.nextInt(size);
int q = ran.nextInt(size-1);

if (q>=p){
    q++;
}
```

Comment: I would argue that manual incrementing/decrementing of a number makes it calculated, not random. But I suppose that's a philosophical point

Comment: +1 for avoiding the potential Θ(∞) running time of other solutions. (That hardly matters in practice but whatever.)

Comment: q IS random, the increment is just there to make sure the end result covers the interval [0,n)

Comment: @Jeff Unless the `java.util.Random` uses a hardware RNG, all the numbers it spits out are going to be "calculated". (And not random under the strict definition of the word.)

Comment: Even if it did have a hardware RNG, the result of that would have to be transformed to get it into the specific range required by the nextInt call. This is just another step in the same process.

Comment: It is slightly less uniform, i.e. the chance of q-p==1 is now twice the chance of q-p==2.

Comment: @greyfairer There is exactly one nextInt result that makes q-p==1, exactly one nextInt result that makes q-p==2 etc. It is not just adding one of the results are equal, but if the raw q result is not less than p.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan oh, yeah, missed that. if(q>=p) iso if q==p. +1!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `1 to n` in a `List`. Then use [Collection.Shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to shuffle the whole `list`. It will shuffle the list with equal likelihood. Then get any 2 from the list

For example

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 1;i <= n; i++)
    a.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(a);
int first = (int)a.get(0);
int second = (int)a.get(1);
```

Comment: +1 for being a solution which actually "generates" the two numbers itself, guaranteed, rather than simply getting two numbers and having to perform comparisons.  Good idea.

Comment: Shuffling the entire list is wasteful. Just swap the first element with a random element, and the second element with a random element. (Shuffling does exactly this, only with the entire list. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle .)

Comment: You should know, however, that your example won't compile.  An `ArrayList` holds `Object`s, which can't be cast to `int`.  You will want to instead cast them to `Integer` and rely on auto-unboxing.

Comment: @jeff really?? .. just check by compiling .. you will see the magic :p

Comment: @StinePike Really.  Unless my Eclipse is lying to me.  Haha.  http://imgur.com/IPvyE6C

Comment: @Jeff.. which jdk are you using?? this code runs in my eclipse.. I am using 1.7

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is:

1. Generate first number
2. Generate second number
3. While second number equals to first number return to step 2

In almost 100% step 2 will be executed no more than a couple of times.

But ensure than n is more than 1 because you will have an endless loop in another case (but anyway, you can't get correct results with any algorithm)